# Kafka-Connect add SQL JAR file to classpath

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to deploy a connect-standalone job to stream from an `mssql` server however am facing an issue (Kafka-Connect is part of my Ambari deployment, not docker). This is the properties file I am using:

```
name=JdbcSourceConnector
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.user=ue
connection.password=pw
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://servername
topic.prefix=iblog
query=SELECT * FROM IB_WEBLOG_DUMMY_small
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
poll.interval.ms=5000
table.poll.interval.ms=120000
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=ID
```

I have added the `jar` file `sqljdbc42.jar` to `/usr/share/java`
and have run `export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/*`

however I still run into the error `Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector`

Am I doing anything wrong or can I check something else?

Answer (score 2):

> Kafka-Connect is part of my Ambari deployment

That would imply you are using Hortonworks installation

You need to

1. `git clone https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/`
2. Checkout a release branch that ideally matches your Kafka version. For example branch `v3.1.2` is [Kafka 0.10.1.1](https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.2/release-notes.html)
3. `mvn clean package` will generate some folders in `target/` of that project
4. SCP those files to all Kafka Connect workers in your cluster into `/usr/hdp/current/kafka/.../share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` (create this, if not exists)
5. Restart Kafka processes to pick up the new CLASSPATH settings

You may need some extra Confluent packages that JDBC connect depends on

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `kafka-connect-jdbc` jar file, which contains the `io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector` class.

If you are using maven, you can add it as a dependency:

> [Add the following repo to your project if you haven't done so yet.]
>
> ```
> <repository>
>   <id>confluent</id>
>   <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
> </repository>
> ```
>
> After this, add the following dependency:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
>     <artifactId>kafka-connect-jdbc</artifactId>  
>     <version>3.3.0 (or whatever version you want)</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/356

Comment: So I just need to use intellij, add these to the pom.xml and then deploy the jar to usr/share/java?

Comment: The thing you quoted is how to build the project, not how to deploy it. In other words there is no other project to "add dependency" to

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. with Couchbase connector not found

**ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:113) java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.couchbase.connect.kafka.CouchbaseSourceConnector**

Setting classpath was losing the existing classpath and I couldn't append as the classpath 
I moved the required jar file from kafka-connect-couchase/*.jar files to /path/kafka_verison/libs/
libs is A folder where all the jar file stored.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, I resolved it by running connect-standalone in the root folder of confluent, in my case this was: `/opt/confluent-5.0.1`